# Variable global variable?

Tags: php, variables, global-variables, variable-variables

I'm trying to automatically sanitize input on an array of global variables like so:

```
$sanitize = array('_POST', '_GET', '_REQUEST', '_COOKIE', '_SESSION');
foreach($sanitize as $type){
    $property = trim(strtolower($type), '_');
    $this->$property = $this->cleanse($$type);
}
```

But I get: `Notice: Undefined variable: _REQUEST` (and so on for all of the global variables I'm trying)

Is doing what I'm trying to accomplish actually possible?

Thanks.

Comment: Works on php 5.3 here. Not that it should. variable variables are inherently evil.

Comment: okay, here is an explanation you asked for. [What's the best method for sanitizing user input with PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/129677/whats-the-best-method-for-sanitizing-user-input-with-php)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Doing this on a global scale is typically frowned upon.

I'd recommend using some of PHP's built in [Filters](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.filter.php) to achieve what you want at a local level. That is just filter what you need as you need it.